# iOS – Animate UITableView deselectRow.. with selectedBackgroundView

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, selection

Is it possible to have `UITableView` animate `- deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated` when the cell's `selectedBackgroundView` is an `UIImageView`?

I would like to have the image fade out like it does when it's a fill color.

Answer (score 0):

In my project i have picture for selected state and implementing it in this way:

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239/255.0 green:237/255.0 blue:231/255.0 alpha:1.0];
cell.backgroundView = background;

UIView *selectedBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
selectedBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selecetedCell.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackground;
```

Maybe it will suitable for you

Comment: Yes, I know how to **set** the `selectedBackgroundView`. I'm asking how to animate the `UIImageView` from selected to not selected.